# field definition in SQL LOADER

Tags: sql-loader

into an SQLLoader .ctl file I have something like this:

```
TRAILING NULCOLS
(...
id_file      CONSTANT "&1"
...)
```

Can anyone tell me what this means? I don't think this is equivalent with DEFAULT value from SQL, where the value would be "&1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few more tests, it seems that the value "&1" represents the 1st parameter given to the .ctl script

Comment: Can you please show a working example of passing parameters to a control file?  This is a new one to me.Thank you.

Comment: In my test I get a literal "&1" in the column.  I would be interested to see how you are calling `sqlldr`.

Comment: Can you please prove with a working example that the &1 indeed gets replaced with an argument to a control file?

Comment: In my case, a shell scripts in calling the SQL loader command passing it few arguments. It seems that the 1st argument is inserted into the column id_file.